# How to make lookup() look for a larger value?

Tags: google-sheets

According to this document: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570#, it is the behavior of the `lookup` function

> If search_key is not found, the item used in the lookup will be the
>   value that’s immediately smaller in the range provided. For example,
>   if the data set contains the numbers 1, 3, 5 and search_key is 2, then
>   1 will be used for the lookup.

However I want to have `3` returned in my case.

For example, let says I have a data table as such

```
2, class A
4, class B
8, class C
```

If I search this range with value 3, I want the search function can take 4 as a match and return `class B` accordingly

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to let the function return 'class A' but to wrap it in a function that looks as the cell below that:

```
=offset(vlookup(C1,A:B,2),1,0)
```

However I would prefer a different pair of functions:

```
=index(B:B,match(C1,A:A)+1)
```